# How do I delay onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

Im a creating and options menu dynamically, the option menu depends on data that is created during the onCreate() stage.

The problem is that onCreateOptionsMenu() is called before the data is created. Is there a way to execute after onCreate() ?

Thanks 
Fabii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`invalidateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29), but it requires API level 11.

Also, you can choose to override [`onPrepareOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) instead, which will give you to opportunity to modify the menu before it is displayed each time.